# What is the font used in japanese postage stamps for the word NIPPON (日本郵便)?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Japan postage stamps all use the same font for the word NIPPON (日本郵便). I could not find a font that matches the second symbol on stamps. Tried the main Identification sites: WhatTheFont
Identifont
WhatFontIs
Fontspring Matcherator
FontID
Reddit /r/identifythisfont
Find a Font
Fonts in Use on Flickr
Graphic Design SE, this very site.
Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5+ Font Match
FontMatch
Find my Font

Comment: This one seems pretty clear https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/japanese-woman-stamp-picture-id458724469?k=6&m=458724469&s=612x612&w=0&h=Hg0jNRoFeqoEFh5ptCAF3t2o8VJLDMD8H7PrMqq0fBg=

Comment: Yes the symbols that define JAPAN, especially the second "本" does not match the common Japanese fonts

Comment: The samples I could find in Duck Duck Go were not identical, but most of them had the "ni hon" glyphs in a style which resembles or imitates ancient carving writing style, where you could not use a brush to write. There's probably a name for it but I'm not familiar with the terminology. Duck Duck Going for "woodblock" or "carving" brings up samples which imitate conventional brush strokes, often quite stunningly so.

Comment: True! What is this font?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you considered this may not be a font you can download. It may be a custom font.  Not everything is a font you can download.

Comment: OK, but it's been used as the official JAPAN name on stamps   since II War.

Comment: Things like this are usually specified in an official government document.

Comment: WW2 happened before the internet. Be aware this may not be a font in the modern definition of something you can google and download.